# Random Forest Predictions

Tags: r, prediction, random-forest

I am looking for some guidance on a homework assignment I am working on for a class.  We are given a dataset with 14K observations and we are asked to build a prediction model.  I subset the dataset into training and testing (4909 observations), here I am using the caret package, which predicts the last variable "classe".  I pulled out the near zero variables and built the model but when I tried to do predictions I only get 97 predictions back.  I reviewed the help files but still can't figure out where I am going wrong.  Any hints would be appreciated.

Here is the Code:

```
  set.seed(1234)
  pml.training <- read.csv("./data/pml-training.csv")
  #
  library(caret) 
  inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=pml.training$classe, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
  training <- pml.training[inTrain,]
  testing <- pml.training[-inTrain,]

  # Pull out the Near Zero Value (NZV)
  nzv <- nearZeroVar(training, saveMetrics=TRUE)
  omit <- which(nzv$nzv==TRUE)
  training <- training[,-omit]
  testing <- testing[,-omit]

  # Fit the model 
  modFit <- train(classe ~., method="rf", data=training)
  modFit
  print(modFit$finalModel)
  plot(modFit)

  # Try and predict on the testing model 
  pred <- predict(modFit, newdata=testing)
  testing$predRight <- pred==testing$classe
  print(table(pred, testing$classe))
```

Thanks, Pat C.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked

```
sum(complete.cases(subset(testing, select = -classe)))
```

?

Comment: Yeah it is 97, so the prediction function is only predicting on complete classes, therefore I should impute data.

Comment: @ptcesq No. An algorithm cannot predict for those cases/observations for which values of the predictor are missing. It predicts those cases where all the predictor values are available (97 in this case). If you would like to predict the rest, you either need to omit those variables in training which are mostly missing in the testing set, or impute the missing values in the testing set.